# 404 not found admin & homepage

Tags: admin, error, 404-page, home-page

I installed magento on my mac osx with xampp as localhost.
After some issues with the installation extension i had been able to install it but now the browser shows a 404 page without style for the homepage

```
http://127.0.0.1/mystore/
```

admin page

```
http://127.0.0.1/shoehappy/admin_mystore
```

Do you have any idea to how solve that mess? thanks

Comment: Haven't used xampp but have used mamp.  have you updated your xampp virtual host?  Also you can make a custom name for that by editing your /etc/hosts file on your mamp computer.  I add ".loc" after mine to mean "local".  Add this (to /etc/hosts file) -> 127.0.0.1 mystore.loc

Answer (score 0):

1. Check server error log files and magento's error log files.
2. Try this one
   Open PhpMyAdmin and run the following query in your database:-

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;